# add random music (defined folder) ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, music

i use my raspberry pi (raspbian) to grab my ip cameras pictures, to create a timelapse with ffmpeg and upload it to youtube automatically every night.

so far so good, but a timelapse without music is boring so i downloaded some copyright free music and put it in a folder.

is it somehow possible to randomly choose 1 title from defined folder and add it to my video.

would be great if i just could drop more music into the folder over time and the script randomly chooses 1 title per video.

at the moment my script looks like this

```
#!/bin/bash
THEDATE=$(date --date="yesterday" +%d.%m.%y)

cd /mnt/pi/timelapse
ffmpeg -r 30 -pattern_type glob -i '*.jpg' -c:v copy -preset slow -pix_fmt yuv420p /mnt/pi/timelapse-$THEDATE.mp4
```

hope this is possible

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer myself.

```
#!/bin/bash
THEDATE=$(date --date="yesterday" +%d.%m.%y)
MUSIC=$(shuf -n1 -e /mnt/pi/youtube-music/*)

cd /mnt/pi/timelapse

ffmpeg -thread_queue_size 512 -r 30 -pattern_type glob -i '*.jpg' -i  $MUSIC -c copy -preset slow -pix_fmt yuv420p -shortest /mnt/pi/timelapse-$THEDATE.mp4
```